# Marshalling a pojo using jaxb results in junk charecters being displayed

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

i am marshalling a pojo using jaxb.

The pojo class contains a variable of type string and the value being set contains the currency symbol in it depending on the java.util.LOCALE being passed.

My problem is while passing LOCALE.US , its working fine (eg. $235.36) but while passing any other LOCALE , say LOCALE.CHINA , a junk character is appended in front of the currency symbol (eg. ï¿¥235.36).

Any suggestions,answers and experiences related to such scenario are most welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a JAXB implementation will output to UTF-8.  You can specify another encoding using the `JAXB_ENCODING` property (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html).  Also note JAXB may be handling the character correctly but the viewer you are using to examine the XML may not.